# Slow write and inconsistant write to MongoDB via C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, performance

**Problem**:
We are experiencing slow write and the time varies greatly between writes. From just over 1 minute to almost 4 minutes. This is to insert a large amount of values (704 974 to be precise)

**Background**:
We read the values in from a txt file, link it to a certain tag (data object) and then add the values to a value collection. Each data point is linked to a tag and a time. Each value bson has two primary keys: ID, and tag-date.
The value Bson looks as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId,
    "Timestamp" : ISODate,
    "TagID" : ObjectId,
    "Value" : string or double,
    "FileReferenceID" : ObjectId,
    "WasValueInterpolated" : int
}
```

The mongoDb is set as a 3 replication set, and we write with writeconcern true (we have had trouble where one replicating set would fall behind and refuse to auto catch up) The Mongo's run on a MESOS/Linux deployment, while the c# code connects over the network from a windows machine.

Mongo version: 3.4.5

C# driver: 2.4.4

I have also increased the min and max threadpool thread counts by 50. I leverage threads to try and increase the write speed, it somewhat works.

**Code**
The actual piece of the code that inserts the data into mongo is this:

```
public int InsertValues(string aDatabaseName, List<cValueDocument> aValues, out List<int> aErrorValueIndexes,
        bool aOverride = false)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(aValues, aValue => aValue.ConvertToDoubleIfCan());
        int lResult = 0;
        Stack<int> lErrorIndexesToDelete = new Stack<int>(aValues.Count - 1);

        aErrorValueIndexes = new List<int>(aValues.Count);
        aDatabaseName = aDatabaseName.ToLower();

        var lValueCollection =
            MongoDatabasesDict[aDatabaseName].GetCollection<cValueDocument>(tMongoCollectionNames.Value.ToString());
        var lTagCollection =
            MongoDatabasesDict[aDatabaseName].GetCollection<cTagDocument>(tMongoCollectionNames.Tag.ToString());

        List<cValueDocument> lValuesOrderedByTime = aValues.OrderBy(aDocument => aDocument.Timestamp).ToList();

        // Check if there are Values that belong to other Tags.
        if (lValuesOrderedByTime.Any(aValue => aValue.TagID != lValuesOrderedByTime[0].TagID))
        {
            return -4;
        }

        cTagDocument lTagDocument = lTagCollection.AsQueryable().First(aTag => aTag._id == lValuesOrderedByTime[0].TagID);

        // Find any Values that are not at least the minimum Interval between each other.
        for (int i = 1; i < lValuesOrderedByTime.Count; i++)
        {
            // Determine if the two consecutive timestamps are not at least an Interval from each other.
            if (lTagDocument.IntervalMask.CompareDateTimesWithinInterval(lValuesOrderedByTime[i - 1].Timestamp, lValuesOrderedByTime[i].Timestamp) == -1)
            {
                aErrorValueIndexes.Add(aValues.FindIndex(aElement => aElement == lValuesOrderedByTime[i]));
                lErrorIndexesToDelete.Push(i);
                lResult = -2;
            }
        }

        // Determine if erroneous values must be removed before insertion.
        if (lResult == -2)
        {
            // Remove each value with an index in lErrorIndexesToDelete;
            while (lErrorIndexesToDelete.Count > 0)
            {
                lValuesOrderedByTime.RemoveAt(lErrorIndexesToDelete.Pop());
            }
        }

        if (aOverride)
        {//removed for testing purposes}

        try
        {
            try
            {
                InsertManyOptions lOptions = new InsertManyOptions();
                lOptions.IsOrdered = false;
                lValueCollection.InsertMany(lValuesOrderedByTime, lOptions);
            }
            catch (MongoBulkWriteException lException)
            {
                if (lException.WriteErrors?.First().Code == 11000)
                {
                    aErrorValueIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, aValues.Count).ToList();
                    lResult = -3;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return lResult;
        }
        catch (Exception lException)
        {
            BigDBLog.LogEvent("Error, an exception was thrown in InsertValues. ", tEventEscalation.Error,
                false,
                lException);
            return -5;
        }
    }
```

I removed some of the value checking to shorten the function.
Basically the function pushes aValues to the mongo

**Debug/Tracing**
Here is where it gets a strange for me. I use the same file to test it. I delete the values from the DB before each test.

The executing speed goes from just over 1 minute to just below 4 minutes. 
I did a trace on the program using jetbrains dotTrace. It points to MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytes as the hot spot. If you follow the code, this was called form  MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.InsertMany. This is weird as I am writing the the DB and not reading from it. The CPU uses does spike (more during the translation of the file), but stays low (1-2%).

I have checked the wiredTiger.concurrentTransactions tickets. They dont run out.

**Questions**

1. How can I improve my read speed (at worst 3175 values/s, at best
   8392 values/s)?
2. Why do I have such inconsistencies? I dont really believe it can all be network related.
3. Why does it read bytes so much and why is it causes
   a bottleneck?
4. What can I further do to help find the problem?